# -moz-linear-gradient with PNG background over top

Tags: css, gradient

So Firefox supports gradient Backgrounds. Also supports multiple Background images.. So why does this not work??

```
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #5989bd,#336296), url(Active-Arrow.png) right center no-repeat;
```

Also tried:

```
background-color:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #5989bd,#336296);
background:url(Active-Arrow.png) right center no-repeat;
```

Can this be done??

Comment: try the first way but as background-image vs just background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must include the background image **BEFORE** the linear gradient. e.g:

```
background: url("http://127.0.0.1/css/bg.png") no-repeat, 
-moz-linear-gradient(top left, rgb(0,255,0), rgb(255,0,0));
```